# Append conditions to entity query

Tags: 8, database

I'm currently performing an entity query like so.

```
$search = 'test';
$type = 'page';
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
    ->condition('type',$type);
```

I'm then adding an 'or' condition like so

```
$or_condition = $query->orConditionGroup()
    ->condition('title', '%'.$search.'%', 'like')
    ->condition('body', '%'.$search.'%', 'like');
$query->condition($or_condition);
$query->execute();
```

This works with no issue, but I would like to be able to continue to add conditions to the $or_condition. Here is my attempt.

```
$search[0] = 'test';
$search[1] = 'test2';

$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
    ->condition('type',$type);

$or_condition = $query->orConditionGroup()
    ->condition('title', '%'.$search[0].'%', 'like')
    ->condition('body', '%'.$search[0].'%', 'like');
$or_condition->condition('title', '%'.$search[1].'%', 'like')
    ->condition('body', '%'.$search[1].'%', 'like');
$query->condition($or_condition);
$query->execute();
```

However the code above does not work.
The ultimate goal is to be able to explode a user provided string and include it into the or condition so the word order of what the user searches doesn't matter.
Is there a way to append conditions to an or condition group outside of the declaration statement?

Comment: this should work, but like is not a supported condition by entity query, it has CONTAINS, ENDS_WITH, STARTS_WITH. Don't use %. Also, sounds like you might want to use search_api instead as adding a lot of conditions like this is going to be pretty inefficient.

Comment: Try putting each set in a separate OR condition, and group both sets in a larger OR condition. It sounds useless, but it might work.